# Fetching error message in Mule 4 not working

Tags: error-handling, mule, mulesoft, mule4

I run the code in debug mode and realized that external service is returning me error message below error message is coming in the path
error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value
Its value is as below.

```
typedValue.value = {"status"":"Bad Request", "message":"Invalid data"}
```

I want to get the message "Invalid data" in var.

My code is as follows

```
output application/java 
var adminEmail = vars.adminEmail
var salesRepEmail = if (!isEmpty(vars.InitialRequest.Application.PreliminaryQuestions.SalesRepresentative.EmailAddress))
                        [vars.InitialRequest.Application.PreliminaryQuestions.SalesRepresentative.EmailAddress]
                    else
                        p('emailNotifications.nonStarterNotification.defaultEmail') splitBy(",")

var declineReason = error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value
```

I have tried

```
var declineReason = if(error == null) vars.errorDescription else (error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value default "Bad request") as String
```

Also tried

```
var declineReason = if(error == null) vars.errorDescription else flatten(error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value.message)
```

error.exception.cause.errorMessage.typedValue.value returns null.

Comment: Please read in detail How to ask a good question in the help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then improve your question. Note that you are mixing the error handling from Mule 4 (`error.`) with variables (`vars.`) from your application that we don't have any context for. Also note that MuleSoft is the name of a company, Mule is the name of one of their products in which your application is executing. Anypoint Studio is the IDE where you debug but that's incidental to the issue.

Comment: @aled is absolutley right, question is confuing to answer you. draft a question always in proper format